# bootstrap issue with instagram embed in react

Tags: reactjs, instagram, embed

I am trying to embed instagram posts onto my page with a masonry grid (using card-columns). But somehow the leftmost posts don't show up.
Please refer to below sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-solomon-ub8ro?file=/src/App.js

Edit:
on full browser tab: https://ub8ro.csb.app/ (you can see the issue here)

Comment: The 5 cards appear when I visit your sandbox.

Comment: try opening the browser in a new tab @known-as-bmf